# Lost files taking up a lot of space on HDD

Tags: filesystem-corruption

I was unzipping a big folder, like 10+ gigs onto my HDD. Unfortunately I ran out of space so it canceled. But being stupid, I quickly x'd out of what it was doing, only to realize it was in the middle of rolling back the changes.

So now I have gigs worth of data somewhere on my HDD, yet search results show nothing. I managed to find it using EaseUS Data recovery, but I don't want to recover it, I just want to delete it all. Also, EaseUS is trying to make me buy their program to do that. Unfortunately, even if I wanted to, right now I only have 2 gigs left of space on my HDD thanks to the lost files, so I don't think I even could recover it if I wanted to.

All in all, I just want to clean all of it away from my HDD. Is there a program that can help?

Comment: If you know the path, navigate to it on your computer. If you're unsure, install `WinDirStat`, locate the directory and right click --> `Delete permanently`

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the path. Here's the weird thing... I was trying to copy it to my D:, which is a normal hard drive. My windows operates on my C:. which is a SSD. Unfortunately, my C:/ doesn't have much space on it.    However for some reason, when I tried extracting it to my D:, which had tons of space left, it gave me an error saying I didn't have enough space. For some reason it was going through my C: to get to my D: if that makes sense.  Now all those gigs are lost somewhere in my C: leaving it packed full of junk I can't find. If I could find the directory, I'd just delete it.

Comment: Nevermind! That program did in fact help me find the folder. $rarSomethingorOther. Thanks!!

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct

Comment: If it truly damaged the file system, then **chkdsk /f c:** should solve it.  You will have to reboot, and then it will do the scan.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is isolate where the temporary directory of the data is stored. Firstly, a general cleanup will work:

`del C:\Windows\Temp\ /F *` and 
`del %tmp%\ /F *` should delete all files in the temporary directory.

Then, perform [Disk Cleanup with the Windows Disk Cleanup Tool](http://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-use-disk-cleanup-in-windows-7-and-vista/).

Now **as I said**, install [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) which will give you a GUI to tell you where the files are.

You could search for [gigantic](http://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-locate-large-files-on-a-hard-drive-using-windows-7/) or search `size:>1gb` in the explorer function.